# How would black blood change a human's appearance?

Tags: science-based, anatomy, blood

Say they had pale skin, what would they look like? Would the lips be black? Would the vascular system show through the skin more? I'm not very interested in how or why their blood is black, just how it would effect their appearance overall.

Comment: Caucasians look pink because our skin is partially transparent, and light refracts through the blood vessels.  So black blood would likely give us a darker appearance, depending how much melanin was in our skins.

Comment: Would this appear slightly grey?

Comment: No more red eyes on pictures taken with flash.

Comment: Probably more like a dark charcoal, depending on the light.

Comment: @AJD. Black and white together make gray, so probably. Blushing would look interesting. I'm also imagining a black heart being a symbol of good heath(instead of evil).

Comment: @Necessity Skin isn't actually white though.  Colour comes from melanin.  Skin is actually translucent - any white is just from refraction of light as it passes through the outer layers.

Comment: Our veins are blue, and we see them as blue, but that does not give us a blue hue all over.

Comment: Naughty pictures from a few decades back will be censored with big **pink** bars instead of black...

Comment: May you have good health: 

Comment: @JustinThyme :[This article](http://scienceblogs.com/scientificactivist/2008/04/17/why-are-veins-blue/) goes into quite some detail about why they look blue when they’re actually more maroon. Turns out arteries would look blue if they were in the right place!

Answer (score 7):

In cold conditions and when sedentary these people would appear corpse like with very pale skin is if they had [pallor mortis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallor_mortis)

In warm conditions or after vigorous exercise these people would appear in shades of grey as if they were a living black and white photo, although given their coloured surroundings a lot more creepy. They would not look exactly like that due to other factors such as eye colour, hairy colour, other elements in the skin and clothing, but it would be a good approximation especialy if naked.

[image: grey man at angels landing]

Comment: @Tim B. Sure I will do that in the next hour or two. However I am concerned that most of the pictures posted on this site fall into this category.

Comment: @Slarty Any that get spotted get tidied up - if you see any unattributed images then please leave a comment and if the poster doesn't fix it then flag it for a moderator's attention with a custom flag.

Comment: Did you just convert that dude's skin to black and white? Why couldn't it have some brownish pigmentation on the surface, similar to the girl in the pink T-shirt, for example?

Comment: @Headcrab yes just converted it to black and white. It could have had some brownish pigmentation. But for coloured skin I would imagine the difference would not be as noticeable due to the variations in brown pigmentation already present. More to the point it would have been more complex to do a black and white with brown skin with my level of Photoshop skills (and this was already my second attempt..)

Comment: @Slarty All kinds of crazy visual effects happen in the skin. Our blood is red, yet our veins under the skin look greenish-bluish. If you consume a lot of silver so that it accumulates in your skin, your skin looks blue (not silver, not gray). If that's gold instead of silver, it looks gray (not gold, not even yellow). We probably wouldn't know the answer to "What if the blood was black?" until we catch some victims and pump them full of black fluid. Probably not even then.

Answer (score 6):

Some thoughts here...

- Consider when someone blushes -- the red is pretty obvious.
- Now consider when someone is about to faint ("goes white" they say).  This condition is often described as someone turning ashen.

So clearly the blood is a factor.  I can imagine people looking more or less as per standard, though with a bit of a goth look ... lips might be more or less dark gray, and the skin would be pale with the dark underneath, might look "waxy", because the top layers of the skin are a bit translucent.  Their tongues would be black, too.

On these guys, "bloodshot" eyes for heavy drinkers would look **creepy and awful**.

Side note: there'd be no emo or goth phenomenon, because, well, what's the point?  Their parents have it covered...

Comment: There could be a goth equivalent as colours might not have the same meaning. Just replace black with, say, neon yellow...

Comment: Gah! Pot smokers will look constantly possessed

Comment: Oh god I never thought about bloodshot eyes. That would be very disturbing. And awesome.

Comment: @AJD. admittedly there is a fine line between "creepy and awful" and "awesome".  ;D  I wonder if these guys' look would be enough to kick off an "uncanny valley" effect.